# "docker start" doesn't make a stopping container be "up"

Tags: windows, docker

`docker start` doesn't make a stopping container be "up".

As the following commands, I wanted to start up a stopping container `eloquent_hamilton`(Container ID:b2b7883c8620) whose status is `Exited (0)` , so I used `docker start eloquent_hamilton` or `docker start b2b7883c8620`.
However, the status of  `eloquent_hamilton` is still `Exited (0)`.

The common case seems that just typing `docker start [Container ID]` makes the status of the container be "UP" until the user explicitly send command for killing or exiting the running container.

What is wrong?

The environment is the following

- host OS: windows10
- Docker: Docker Desktop for Windows

Any information would be appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Naoki>docker images
REPOSITORY                 TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
forcattranslator/hello     latest        64c8ea9561cc   About an hour ago   72.8MB
forcattranslator/myjulia   latest        84ec6294d0dc   2 days ago          4.24GB
hassiweb/myjulia           julia-1.6.2   84ec6294d0dc   2 days ago          4.24GB

C:\Users\Naoki>docker run -it forcattranslator/hello
"hello docker!"

C:\Users\Naoki>docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                       NAMES
b2b7883c8620   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     21 seconds ago   Exited (0) 19 seconds ago                                               eloquent_hamilton
f7c65f29f81b   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     48 seconds ago   Exited (0) 46 seconds ago                                               admiring_tereshkova
c47ac4b56d64   forcattranslator/hello         "bash"                   7 minutes ago    Up 5 minutes                                                            thirsty_carson
9c83d47cfea2   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     9 minutes ago    Exited (0) 7 minutes ago                                                gifted_feynman
9d17957f8e43   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     18 minutes ago   Exited (0) 17 minutes ago                                               laughing_albattani
43b967492f0c   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     46 minutes ago   Exited (0) 22 minutes ago                                               sad_wu
f97a713d6889   hassiweb/myjulia:julia-1.6.2   "tini -g -- start-no…"   2 days ago       Up 2 days                   0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, :::8888->8888/tcp   docker-julia_julia_1

C:\Users\Naoki>docker start eloquent_hamilton
eloquent_hamilton

C:\Users\Naoki>docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                                       NAMES
b2b7883c8620   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     About a minute ago   Exited (0) 4 seconds ago                                                    eloquent_hamilton
f7c65f29f81b   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                                               admiring_tereshkova
c47ac4b56d64   forcattranslator/hello         "bash"                   8 minutes ago        Up 6 minutes                                                                thirsty_carson
9c83d47cfea2   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     10 minutes ago       Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                                                    gifted_feynman
9d17957f8e43   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     19 minutes ago       Exited (0) 17 minutes ago                                                   laughing_albattani
43b967492f0c   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     47 minutes ago       Exited (0) 22 minutes ago                                                   sad_wu
f97a713d6889   hassiweb/myjulia:julia-1.6.2   "tini -g -- start-no…"   2 days ago           Up 2 days                       0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, :::8888->8888/tcp   docker-julia_julia_1
```

### Progress

Following the answer, I tried `docker start -i eloquent_hamilton`,adding `-i` option to keep the communication interactive, but the result is still finding the status of the container be `Exited(0)`.

```
docker start -i eloquent_hamilton
"hello docker!"

C:\Users\Naoki\tmp>docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                      PORTS                                       NAMES
b2b7883c8620   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     22 hours ago   Exited (0) 16 seconds ago                                               eloquent_hamilton
f7c65f29f81b   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     22 hours ago   Exited (0) 22 hours ago                                                 admiring_tereshkova
c47ac4b56d64   forcattranslator/hello         "bash"                   22 hours ago   Exited (255) 20 hours ago                                               thirsty_carson
9c83d47cfea2   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     23 hours ago   Exited (0) 22 hours ago                                                 gifted_feynman
9d17957f8e43   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     23 hours ago   Exited (0) 23 hours ago                                                 laughing_albattani
43b967492f0c   forcattranslator/hello         "cat /tmp/hello.txt"     23 hours ago   Exited (0) 23 hours ago                                                 sad_wu
f97a713d6889   hassiweb/myjulia:julia-1.6.2   "tini -g -- start-no…"   3 days ago     Up 20 hours                 0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, :::8888->8888/tcp   docker-julia_julia_1
```

Comment: It starts it, however, if the init process in your container immediately exits, then it won't stay up, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your container is the hello world example container (or based on it). This container contains a single script which outputs something and then immediately afterwards is done. So "starting" it again worked (as on your screenshot you can see it exited 4 seconds ago) but it didn't do much.

Every docker container has a process that defines the container running time. At the point where this process ends, the container stops. In your case, it outputs the hello to somewhere and then quits (hence the "Exited (0) 4 seconds ago").

If you want it to keep running after this you need to make sure that the last process of the container is indefinite. This can be done in several ways, but most commonly you will find software that run for example a webserver.

[EDIT]
In your example you first run with the "-it" flag, meaning the output will be redirected to your terminal (as can be seen in the out "Hello Docker"). The second and third time the container just runs and does not output to the terminal.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe the examples of Docker container I saw was a webserver and that was why the container continued after implementing command.

Answer (score 0):

your container simply cats the file /tmp/hello.txt. As @JustLudo pointed out, when you ran `docker run -it forcattranslator/hello`, the container showed the content of file /tmp/hello.txt to the tty. Then it finished and thus the container was stopped.

When you start the container again, it executes the entry point again (cat /tmp/hello.txt) and finalizes again. That is what the container does, because in the first "run" you did not added any other command.

You can check the output by executing `docker logs eloquent_hamilton` or start the container by making it interactive again by executing `docker start -i eloquent_hamilton`